# How to Interpret Trace Flag 1222 deadlock

Tags: sql-server

please guide me how to read this graph to figure out what is cause for this deadlock . I looked for resources online but didn't find clear information. this is my first time to see this graph

```
deadlock-list
deadlock victim=process49b0a0558
process-list
process id=process49b0a0558 taskpriority=0 logused=644 waitresource=PAGE: 7:1:17238196  waittime=8444 ownerId=4210681187 transactionname=implicit_transaction lasttranstarted=2015-07-23T11:45:10.107 XDES=0x35f5611b8 lockMode=S schedulerid=1 kpid=37892 status=suspended spid=21656 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=1 lastbatchstarted=2015-07-23T11:45:10.263 lastbatchcompleted=2015-07-23T11:45:10.243 lastattention=1900-01-01T00:00:00.243 clientapp=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server hostname=intl.com hostpid=0 loginname=xxx isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=4210681187 currentdb=7 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128058
executionStack
 frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtstart=40 sqlhandle=0x020000003b05030e975dbade26c8bd0a4bd47787a162ef2a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
select distinct collegeatt0_.InstanceId as col_0_0_, transcript2_.BarCode as col_1_0_ from dbo.CollegeAttended collegeatt0_ cross join dbo.CollegeLookup collegeloo1_ cross join dbo.Transcript transcript2_ where collegeloo1_.transcript_code=collegeatt0_.Code and transcript2_.CollegeAttendedId=collegeatt0_.Id and (collegeloo1_.school_code in ('444444') or collegeloo1_.school_state='FR' or collegeloo1_.isforeign=1 or collegeatt0_.Code like 'FR%') and transcript2_.ApplicantCASId=@P0     
 frame procname=unknown line=1 sqlhandle=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
unknown     
inputbuf
(@P0 nvarchar(4000))select distinct collegeatt0_.InstanceId as col_0_0_, transcript2_.BarCode as col_1_0_ from dbo.CollegeAttended collegeatt0_ cross join dbo.CollegeLookup collegeloo1_ cross join dbo.Transcript transcript2_ where collegeloo1_.transcript_code=collegeatt0_.Code and transcript2_.CollegeAttendedId=collegeatt0_.Id and (collegeloo1_.school_code in ('444444') or collegeloo1_.school_state='FR' or collegeloo1_.isforeign=1 or collegeatt0_.Code like 'FR%') and transcript2_.ApplicantCASId=@P0            
  process id=process3b11f90c8 taskpriority=0 logused=748 waitresource=KEY: 7:72057594521583616 (0522e5133bfc) waittime=6368 ownerId=4210680811 transactionname=implicit_transaction lasttranstarted=2015-07-23T11:45:09.927 XDES=0x48516a3a8 lockMode=S schedulerid=2 kpid=62220 status=suspended spid=11876 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=1 lastbatchstarted=2015-07-23T11:45:12.380 lastbatchcompleted=2015-07-23T11:45:12.380 lastattention=1900-01-01T00:00:00.380 clientapp=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server hostname=intl.com hostpid=0 loginname=xxx isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=4210680811 currentdb=7 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128058
executionStack
 frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtstart=40 sqlhandle=0x02000000dbccbf2e4211c587b6da054c320aafc625b87b730000000000000000000000000000000000000000
select vendortran0_.Id as Id1_17_, vendortran0_.ApplicantCASId as Applican2_17_, vendortran0_.barcode as barcode3_17_, vendortran0_.CreatedDate as CreatedD4_17_, vendortran0_.InstanceId as Instance5_17_, vendortran0_.ReceivedDate as Received6_17_, vendortran0_.TranscriptEvaluationType as Transcri7_17_, vendortran0_.TranscriptFileLocation as Transcri8_17_, vendortran0_.UpdatedDate as UpdatedD9_17_ from VendorTranscriptEvaluation vendortran0_ where vendortran0_.ApplicantCASId=@P0     
 frame procname=unknown line=1 sqlhandle=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
unknown     
inputbuf
(@P0 nvarchar(4000))select vendortran0_.Id as Id1_17_, vendortran0_.ApplicantCASId as Applican2_17_, vendortran0_.barcode as barcode3_17_, vendortran0_.CreatedDate as CreatedD4_17_, vendortran0_.InstanceId as Instance5_17_, vendortran0_.ReceivedDate as Received6_17_, vendortran0_.TranscriptEvaluationType as Transcri7_17_, vendortran0_.TranscriptFileLocation as Transcri8_17_, vendortran0_.UpdatedDate as UpdatedD9_17_ from VendorTranscriptEvaluation vendortran0_ where vendortran0_.ApplicantCASId=@P0            
resource-list
 pagelock fileid=1 pageid=17238196 dbid=7 subresource=FULL objectname=unicas_ux.dbo.Transcript id=lock534943880 mode=IX associatedObjectId=72057594520010752
owner-list
 owner id=process3b11f90c8 mode=IX
waiter-list
 waiter id=process49b0a0558 mode=S requestType=wait
 keylock hobtid=72057594521583616 dbid=7 objectname=unicas_ux.dbo.VendorTranscriptEvaluation indexname=IX_VendorTranscriptEvaluation id=lock43924a180 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057594521583616
owner-list
 owner id=process49b0a0558 mode=X
waiter-list
 waiter id=process3b11f90c8 mode=S requestType=wait
```

Comment: I want to add a notice that deadlock is coming from 2 select statements

Comment: why wouldn't selects deadlock each other (depending on the isolation level)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826600/transaction-deadlock-for-select-query or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661908/sql-server-deadlocks-between-select-update-or-multiple-selects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some ways to view a visual representation of the deadlock graph xml.

In my opinion the best tool is [SQL Sentry plan explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view.asp) which has a free trial.

Depending on the version (I seem to recall 2012) SQL Server Management studio offers a graphical view of the deadlock XML as well.

Please read to this [great explanation of Jonathan Kehayias](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/handling-deadlocks-in-sql-server/) to get the essence of how to investigate with SQL standard tooling:

Answer (score 2):

@Tom V has mentioned almost the great references to troubleshoot deadlock.

In addition to them as you posted for trace flag 1222 output from logs on deadlock you can analyse this with help of Bart's article [Deadlock Troubleshooting, Part 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20160206200456/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/bartd/archive/2006/09/09/deadlock-troubleshooting_2c00_-part-1.aspx) and [Deadlock Troubleshooting, Part 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bartd/deadlock-troubleshooting-part-2)

It greatly explains how to analyse the log that will help you analysing the deadlock, which should be a good kickstart.

Comment: Any idea why the deadlock happen from 2 select statement?

Comment: the deadlock involves both statements, please analyse according to the links provided. There is no single statement deadlocking

Comment: Thanks @tomv , sorry if my question was not clear. i meant Both queries involved in this deadlock are Select .... there is no any ( insert , update or delete). i  am checking the links provided

Comment: @sebeid maybe you should read the articles included in the link. They will probably explain how you are getting this deadlock. Although I will warn that deadlock troubleshooting can be quite tricky.

Comment: @Zane the trouble with deadlocks is that it's not a pure sql problem but involves application code